# iOS application glitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am working on debugging an app and there is a glitch. I looked it up on the app and also in the internet but did not find anything.

You can reach the glitch from below

[image]

It looks like below for that short time interval.

[image]

**My code:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.item == 0) {
    HGOtherUserTopInformationCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifierForTopInfoCellProfile forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.user = [HGUser currentUser];
    cell.amIFollowing = false;
    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.viewController = self;
    return cell;
}else{
    if (indexPath.item % 2 != 0) {
        HGSeperatorCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifierForSeperatorCellProfile forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        return cell;
    }else{
        HGActivity * activity = self.profileActivities[(indexPath.item - 2) / 2];
        if ([activity.activityType isEqualToString:kActivityKeyUserPublishedResponse]) {
            // Response
            HGResponse * response = activity.response;
            if ([response.mediaType isEqualToString:@"Photo"]) {
                HGOtherUserPhotoCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifierForPhotoCellProfile forIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.response = response;
                cell.indexPath = indexPath;
                cell.baseDelegate = self;
                if (userLikedResponses) {
                    if ([userLikedResponses containsObject:response.objectId]) {
                        cell.liked = true;
                    }else{
                        cell.liked = false;
                    }
                }
                cell.viewController = self;
                if (joinedChallenges) {
                    bool joined = false;
                    for (HGActivity * joinedChallengeActivity in joinedChallenges) {
                        if ([joinedChallengeActivity.challenge.objectId isEqualToString:response.challenge.objectId]) {
                            joined = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    cell.joined = joined;
                }else{
                    cell.joined = false;
                }
                return cell;
            }else if ([response.mediaType isEqualToString:@"Video"]) {
                HGOtherUserVideoCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifierForVideoCellProfile forIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.response = response;
                cell.indexPath = indexPath;
                cell.baseDelegate = self;
                if (userLikedResponses) {
                    if ([userLikedResponses containsObject:response.objectId]) {
                        cell.liked = true;
                    }else{
                        cell.liked = false;
                    }
                }
                if (indexPath.item == 2) {
                    [cell playMuted];
                }
                cell.viewController = self;
                if (joinedChallenges) {
                    bool joined = false;
                    for (HGActivity * joinedChallengeActivity in joinedChallenges) {
                        if ([joinedChallengeActivity.challenge.objectId isEqualToString:response.challenge.objectId]) {
                            joined = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    cell.joined = joined;
                }else{
                    cell.joined = false;
                }
                return cell;
            }else{
                HGOtherUserMedialessCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifierForMedialessCellProfile forIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.response = response;
                cell.indexPath = indexPath;
                cell.baseDelegate = self;
                if (userLikedResponses) {
                    if ([userLikedResponses containsObject:response.objectId]) {
                        cell.liked = true;
                    }else{
                        cell.liked = false;
                    }
                }
                cell.viewController = self;
                if (joinedChallenges) {
                    bool joined = false;
                    for (HGActivity * joinedChallengeActivity in joinedChallenges) {
                        if ([joinedChallengeActivity.challenge.objectId isEqualToString:response.challenge.objectId]) {
                            joined = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    cell.joined = joined;
                }else{
                    cell.joined = false;
                }
                return cell;
            }
        }else{
            // Challenge
            HGChallenge * challenge = activity.challenge;
            if ([challenge.mediaType isEqualToString:@"Photo"]) {
                HGOtherUserPhotoCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifierForPhotoCellProfile forIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.challenge = challenge;
                cell.indexPath = indexPath;
                cell.baseDelegate = self;
                if (userLikedChallenges) {
                    if ([userLikedChallenges containsObject:challenge.objectId]) {
                        cell.liked = true;
                    }else{
                        cell.liked = false;
                    }
                }
                cell.viewController = self;
                if (joinedChallenges) {
                    bool joined = false;
                    for (HGActivity * joinedChallengeActivity in joinedChallenges) {
                        if ([joinedChallengeActivity.challenge.objectId isEqualToString:challenge.objectId]) {
                            joined = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    cell.joined = joined;
                }else{
                    cell.joined = false;
                }
                return cell;
            }else if ([challenge.mediaType isEqualToString:@"Video"]) {
                HGOtherUserVideoCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifierForVideoCellProfile forIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.challenge = challenge;
                cell.indexPath = indexPath;
                cell.baseDelegate = self;
                if (userLikedChallenges) {
                    if ([userLikedChallenges containsObject:challenge.objectId]) {
                        cell.liked = true;
                    }else{
                        cell.liked = false;
                    }
                }
                if (indexPath.item == 2) {
                    [cell playMuted];
                }
                cell.viewController = self;
                if (joinedChallenges) {
                    bool joined = false;
                    for (HGActivity * joinedChallengeActivity in joinedChallenges) {
                        if ([joinedChallengeActivity.challenge.objectId isEqualToString:challenge.objectId]) {
                            joined = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    cell.joined = joined;
                }else{
                    cell.joined = false;
                }
                return cell;
            }else{
                HGOtherUserMedialessCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifierForMedialessCellProfile forIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.challenge = challenge;
                cell.indexPath = indexPath;
                cell.baseDelegate = self;
                if (userLikedChallenges) {
                    if ([userLikedChallenges containsObject:challenge.objectId]) {
                        cell.liked = true;
                    }else{
                        cell.liked = false;
                    }
                }
                cell.viewController = self;
                if (joinedChallenges) {
                    bool joined = false;
                    for (HGActivity * joinedChallengeActivity in joinedChallenges) {
                        if ([joinedChallengeActivity.challenge.objectId isEqualToString:challenge.objectId]) {
                            joined = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    cell.joined = joined;
                }else{
                    cell.joined = false;
                }
                return cell;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it occur after scrolling?

Comment: You are not "reusing" tableview cell, in right way.

Comment: @SaurabhJain, Thanks for pointing and guiding. Can you please look into the first revision of question and update my revision so that I can get loop holes in my revision.

Comment: First time asking, did not ask a proper question I guess. @SaurabhJain, it happens when I change tabs.

Comment: @Alp show your code of cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: @SaurabhJain You can check my code above.

Comment: Note the solution, but. If that's your final code, I'd strongly suggest to rework it. You may want to use a ParentClassCustomCell since they have a lot in commune. Also, for your cells, you may provide method to fill them, because they are too much of "cell.property1=...;cell.property2=...;` which make harder to read afterwards. Regroup the Cell Classes Hierarchy.

Comment: @Larme Thank you for your suggestions. I will keep those in mind. We will rework it but we needed a fast solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem about reloadData. Old code was like the below

```
[weakSelf.collectionView reloadData];
```

I changed it to this:

```
[weakSelf.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
```

And it solved my problem. There is no more a glitch in the text but a glitch on the pictures. But it looked cool so I am keeping it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing many custom cells depending on the conditions, then you have to properly reuse the tableview cells.create a common UITableViewCell class (In your case for eg: HGCell) for UI you can create many nib's as per your need (eg: HGOtherUserTopInformationCell, HGSeperatorCell...). below code show you the example to handle many cells.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%ld",(long)indexPath.row];

    NSString *nibName;

    if(indexPath.item == 0)
    {
        nibName = @"HGOtherUserTopInformationCell";
    }
    else
    {
        if (indexPath.item % 2 != 0)
        {
            nibName = @"HGSeperatorCell";
        }
        else
        {
            nibName = @"HGOtherUserPhotoCell";
        }
    }

    HGCell *cell = (HGCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (HGCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //access the cell property here
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    return cell;
}
```